# Why AllowPaging = true; isn't showing Page Numbering at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, spgridview

when I try,

```
GridView.PageSize = 5;
GridView.AllowPaging = true;
GridView.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(GridView_PageIndexChanging);
```

and I got this,

```
void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView != null)
    {

        GridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Why I am not able to see page numbering at all, I am 100% sure there are more then 5 rows as when I increase pageSize property I can see them.

Comment: Please post the `GridView` aspx code

Comment: there isn't any, as I am using  SPGridView, please get code from my this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064116/confusion-with-spgridview-not-much-different-from-gridview

Comment: what's your code in Page_Load?

Answer (score 0):

add in code:

```
GridView.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.Numeric;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding your control dynamically, you will have to add your control to your page BEFORE you call your DataBind() method, otherwise it won't show the numer of pages.